# Deeplearning4j, why is there a method to specify the number of outputs of each layer in convolutional neural networks?

Tags: conv-neural-network, deeplearning4j

I was wondering why there is a method .nOut() that needs to be specified at each convolutional layer of a neural network in DeepLearning4j. Isn't the number of outputs dependent on the size of the kernel, the stride and the size of inputs? It also only takes one parameter, what if I want to specify both the width and length of my output at each convolutional layer, how do I do that? When I try not using this method, it makes my output 0 by default which throws an InvalidConfigurationException at runtime.

```
.layer(1, new ConvolutionLayer.Builder(kernelHeight, kernelWidth)
    .stride(verticalStride, horizontalStride)
    .nOut(numberOfOutputs)        //This is what I don't understand
    .activation(Activation.IDENTITY)
    .build())
```

Comment: Please ask this to our developer community on Gitter: https://gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j